# Adding "test name: test result" to TFS notification email

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, mstest

I have a project with unit tests running on TFS with scheduled builds. I receive e-mail notifications like:
[Standard email notification on build completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMamD.png)

I need to add a list of tests with test results and test error message to the notification mail. Is it possible to do it with TFS?
If not, how can i configure an extra step to the build definition with unit tests data like "unit test name: result" (completed/failed) + error message.
It would also be a good point to add an attachment with test results to the email.

Please provide me with information/instructions/examples.

The project with unit tests is coded using c# and MSTests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build alert template is located at:

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application
> Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033\BuildCompletedEvent.xsl

Find the template you could do customization in it.

Also, You could write a powershell script to get test results then send emails. Then run this script in TFS build.

To get test results using from TFS RESI API: [How can I get the last test run id from TFS to my powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424694/how-can-i-get-the-last-test-run-id-from-tfs-to-my-powershell-script)

Send email using powershell: https://practical365.com/exchange-server/powershell-how-to-send-email/

Here is also another blog with codes: http://chamindac.blogspot.sg/2015/10/send-test-result-email-after-running.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have already looked through the template files and installed an "email" extension (by the way, the one you mentions didn't work for me somehow, had to install https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions). The question still remains - i didn't find a way to refer to test names or test results. I've tried to view all variables, but there is no information related to test results except for "common.testresultsdirectory" variable which doesn't help.

Comment: @Tef  sorry, there's no build variables about test results. I have updated the reply