# Azure DO: Get test run id from Publish results task

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the Azure DO pipeline to run the test, and in the end, I have the Publish test results task. The task produces a link to test results which looks something like: `https://.../.../.../.../Runs?runId=1031864&_a=runCharts`. Is there any way to get `runId` (1031864 in the example) or the whole link to use it as a variable in the following tasks? I've tried to assign `runId` in the release variables and to pass it in the following tasks, which does not give the result. Could someone help? Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand all of your question, but the run Id is stored in `BUILD_BUILDID`. You can read out inside a script with `$env:BUILD_BUILDID` for build- & releasepipelines. If I understand something wrong, please ignore it.

Comment: @user270219 Not get your latest information, do you try the script I gave below? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @Hugh Lin - MSFT thank you for your answer and support! I've tried the script below, but I have an issue with passing the variable into the following task. I tried the following expressions (runId variable was assigned as release variable): `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runId]$($result.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"`, `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runId]$result"`, `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runId]$result.id"`.

Comment: In addition, I'm not fully sure, that run id could be set for my release - I'm trying to run the JMeter performance test using command line tasks, and then to prepare a report using Publish Test Results task. When I check the link `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1` I cannot find my release (I guess, because I'm not using any test tasks)

Comment: @user270219 For first comment ,please view my Update2 in the answer. If you want to get runId in release, you only need to add this powershell task(which wrote script to get runId) in your release pipeline,so that you can get runId in release.

Comment: I've added updated scripts to the pipeline and now I'm able to get runId. And how to pass the runId tp the next task? I tried to use $(result), but the variable value is not passed

Comment: @user270219 Please add `@Hugh Lin -MSFT` in front of the comment,otherwise I won’t receive the reminder.

Comment: @Hugh Lin -MSFT sorry, I don't understand , I've added the following line into your PowerShell script: `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runId]$($result.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"`, and I'm trying to use variable `runId` in the following task which does not give the result

Comment: @user270219 I can get the value normally in the subsequent powershell task. Can you tell me which task do you use as the following task ? Do you get the value in the following task in this form:`$(runId)` ?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Using your PowerShell script I can get `results` (as a list of test runs) and `result` (as the last test run id), e.g. `2020-01-21T09:13:19.8854908Z result = 1037424`. The next task I have to use is Send an Email - I'd like to send the link to the test result. The Mail body is something like `Performance Test Run Results: 
$(SYSTEM.TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$(SYSTEM.TEAMPROJECT)/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=$($result.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)&_a=runCharts`. And I have to pass run id to this link (after `Runs?runId=`).

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I've tried to paste `result`, and `runId` (which I'm trying to get via `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runId]$($result.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"`), but I'm not succeeded.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Thank you very much ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to get runId or the whole
>   link to use it as a variable in the following tasks?

For this issue ,you can call [Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api with script in a powershell task to get a list of test runs.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1
```

Then we need to get the latest test runId, because the returned result is the latest test run at the bottom, so we need to sort the returned results in descending order.

We could retrieve the list of test runs, the sort descending the result on ID, since the most recent test run has the greatest ID. Then get the first item of the result.

Below is a sample powershell script,for details, you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424694/how-can-i-get-the-last-test-run-id-from-tfs-to-my-powershell-script).

```
$testRuns = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1" -Headers $headers -Method Get 

$testRunsIdSorted = $testRuns.value | sort-object id -Descending

$mostRecentTestRun = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/$($testRunsIdSorted[0].id)?api-version=5.1" -Headers $headers -Method Get
```

After getting the `mostRecentTestRun` ,we can use script `##vso[task.setvariable variable=mostRecentTestRun;isOutput=true]$mostRecentTestRun`" to output it to the following task.

**Update**:

Here is my full script in powershell task:

```
$url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}/{proName}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1';

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get

$testRunsIdSorted = $response.value | sort-object id -Descending

Write-Host "results = $($testRunsIdSorted | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/test/runs/$($testRunsIdSorted[0].id)?api-version=5.1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get

Write-Host "results = $($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

Write-Host "result = $($result.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

For this authentication , you need to click `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` option in Agent job.

[image]

I can get the runId in the output:

[image]

**Update2**:

> have an issue with passing the variable into the following task

For this issue, you need to set variable like below :

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runId]$($result.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Then in the following task , you only need to use this format `$(runId)` to get variable . For example:

```
Write-Host "$(runId)"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've followed your instructions, but I get the following error: `Cannot index into a null array.`, though when I use the URL `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1` I see the list of test runs, what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @user270219 I updated the full script to the answer, you can refer to it.

Comment: How will this behave with parallel running jobs in the same pipeline? I imagine there is a time window when you might get the test run id for another test run.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer given by [Hugh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712182/5260872), I have another solution for this so I'm gonna leave it here.

Instead of querying all Runs, sort by descending and taking the top one, you can also query the Test Run by `BuildUri`, also the results has a `webAccessUrl` so you can directly use that as well which will look like this `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=xxxxxx&_a=runCharts`

```
$url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?buildUri=$(Build.BuildUri)&api-version=7.1';
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Get
$testRunsIdSorted = $response.value | sort-object id -Descending


Write-Host "$($testRunsIdSorted[0].id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
Write-Host "$($testRunsIdSorted[0].webAccessUrl | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunId]$($testRunsIdSorted[0].id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunUrl]$($testRunsIdSorted[0].webAccessUrl | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

You can access these in the later pipeline tasks using `$(RunId)` and `$(RunUrl)`

If you're on a build pipeline, not a release pipeline, `System.AccessToken` variable might not be available. In that case, create a personal access token and set it as a pipeline variable. (In my case it's `AZUREDEVOPS_PAT`)

```
# Call Azure DevOps REST API
$pat = $env:AZUREDEVOPS_PAT

$buildUri = $env:BUILD_BUILDURI

# Call Azure DevOps REST API
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?buildUri=$buildUri&api-version=7.1"

Write-Host "Calling: $($url)"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{
  Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat"))
}

# Parse JSON response
$runId = $response.value.id
$runUrl = $response.value.webAccessUrl

# Set pipeline variables
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunId;]$runId"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunUrl;]$runUrl"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this issue : In Azure DevOps Pipeline, Create a Powershell Task to retrieve the latest Test Run ID. Please follow the steps below :

```
$OrganizationName = "Your Organization Name"

$ProjectName = "Your Project Name"

$PAT = "Your Pat scope to Test management (read) scope at least"

# Base64 encodes the PAT for authentication
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $PAT)))

# API endpoint for getting test run details
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$OrganizationName/$ProjectName/_apis/test/runs?api-version=6.0"

# Send a GET request to the API endpoint
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

# Sort the results and retrieve the latest run ID from the list
$testRunsIdSorted = $response.value | sort-object id -Descending

# Writes customized output to a host and assign to a variable to use it for later Task

Write-Host "$($testRunsIdSorted[0].id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

Write-Host "$($testRunsIdSorted[0].webAccessUrl | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunId]$($testRunsIdSorted[0].id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunUrl]$($testRunsIdSorted[0].webAccessUrl | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunUrl]$($testRunsIdSorted[0].webAccessUrl)"

# To Send an email, I am using the Sendgrid task in Azure DevOps Pipeline.
```

Click on the "+" sign again and select the Sendgrid task.

Configure the task by entering your Sendgrid API key, recipient email address, subject, and message.

Email Body Format:  Inline

Email Body :
$(RunId)
$(RunUrl)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a query option in the rest API, so you can get the actual test run directly from the build id. Inside a pipeline the build id is always available via the Build.BuildId predefined variable. Use this url:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate=2023-03-20&maxLastUpdatedDate=2023-03-23&buildIds=xxxx&api-version=7.0`

Microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1